# best algorithm to reconcile 3 lists

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

i am looking for a way to reconcile elements from 3 different sources. i've simplified the elements to having just a key (string) and version (long).

the lists are attained concurrently (2 from separate database queries, and 1 from a memory cache on another system).

for my end result, i only care about elements that are not identical versions across all 3 sources. So the result i care about would be a list of keys, with corresponding versions in each system.

```
Element1 | system1:v100    | system2:v100 | system3:v101 |
Element2 | system1:missing | system2:v200 | system3:v200 |
```

and the elements with identical versions can be discarded.

The 2 ways of achieving this i thought of are

1. wait for all datasources to finish retrieving, and than loop through each list to aggregate a master list with a union of keys + all 3 versions (discarding all identical items).
2. as soon as the first list is done being retrieved, put it into a concurrent collection such as dictionary (offered in .net 4.0), and start aggregating remaining lists (into the concurrent collection) as soon as they are available.

my thinking is that second approach will be a little quicker, but probably not by much. i can't really do much until all 3 sources are present, so not much is gained from 2nd approach and contention is introduced.

maybe there is a completely other way to go about this? Also, since versions are stored using longs, and there will be 100's of thousands (possibly millions) of elements, memory allocation could be of concern (tho probably not a big concern since these objects are short lived)

Comment: Do all lists have the same size, and does position `i` hold the version of the i-th Element?

Comment: nope.. more often than not, they will be different size. depending on which version is different (or missing), this could be ok, or grounds for warning.

Comment: and order of items will also be different.. i could add sorting of course, but couldn't rely that index will be the same for all items.

Comment: You could if you performed some sort of padding (use the `missing` value from your example). That would cut down the computational complexity quite a bit, since you wouldn't have to search the lists, just access a specific position.

Comment: good point. what if i created a hash for each list, to decrease the search time?

Comment: also, padding is tricky because the value can be missing in any of the lists.. so as i get consecutive lists, i would have to loop through initial ones, add padding, and shift remaining items down.. unless you can think of a faster way ?

Comment: I was thinking the sources should perform the padding themselves when they create the list. The way I see it, I ask them the version of elements 1 to N, and the answer is always a list of size N. If they don't have that element, put `missing`. If that's not possible, adding the padding afterwards does get cumbersome.

Comment: Hold on folks! It seems all these implementation details speak to [plausibly _premature_] optimization! `FIRST` we need to know What is the requirement with regard to the general process: should it be `batched / synchronized`, whereby one new list of discrepancies is produced _after_ all 3 sources have been received, or should it be an `online` process of sorts, whereby list fragments containing one or a few discrepancies are produced shortly after enough info has been received to detect some discrepancies but necessarily for all items and/or from all sources ?

Comment: What is the frequency of this process? How much time goes from the first datasource retrieving to the last datasource's retrieve?

Comment: frequency would be every hour * 30 or so times on each run (checking sets for different accounts etc).. retrieval time of each source (for each account) could take anywhere form 1 to 60 seconds, and the size of each retrieval would be 0 to tens of thousands)

Comment: and the get is not linear since im using multiple threads.. so net retrieve time should be under a minute on average

Comment: @dario_ramos i don't know what the N is .. the list of elements is not something pre-defined. it should be identical in all sources, but any element can be missing in any source (that's the point of this reconciliation). i basically just get the union of all sources to figure out the master list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HashSet is an option as it has Union and Intersect methods

[HashSet.UnionWith Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342097.aspx)

To use this you must override Equals and GetHashCode.
A good (unique) hash is key to performance.

If the version is all v then numeric the could use the numeric to build the hash with missing as 0.
Have Int32 to play with so if version is Int10 or less can create a perfect hash.

Another option is ConcurrentDictionary (there is no concurrent HashSet) and have all three feed into it.
Still need to override Equals and GetHashCode.
My gut feel is three HashSets then Union would be faster.

If all versions are numeric and you can use 0 for missing then could just pack into UInt32 or UInt64 and put that directly in a HashSet.  After Union then unpack.  Use bit pushing << rather than math to pack an unpack.

This is just two UInt16 but it runs in 2 seconds.
This is going to be faster than Hashing classes.

If all three versions are long then HashSet`<integral type>` will not be an option.
long1 ^ long2 ^ long3;  might be a good hash but the is not my expertise.
I know GetHashCode on a Tuple is bad.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HashSetComposite hsc1 = new HashSetComposite();
        HashSetComposite hsc2 = new HashSetComposite();
        for (UInt16 i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            for (UInt16 j = 0; j < 40000; j++)
            {
                hsc1.Add(i, j);
            }
            for (UInt16 j = 20000; j < 60000; j++)
            {
                hsc2.Add(i, j);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(hsc1.Intersect(hsc2).Count().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(hsc1.Union(hsc2).Count().ToString());
    }
}

public class HashSetComposite : HashSet<UInt32>
{
    public void Add(UInt16 u1, UInt16 u2)
    {      
        UInt32 unsignedKey = (((UInt32)u1) << 16) | u2;
        Add(unsignedKey);           
    }
    //left over notes from long
    //ulong unsignedKey = (long) key;
    //uint lowBits = (uint) (unsignedKey & 0xffffffffUL);
    //uint highBits = (uint) (unsignedKey >> 32);
    //int i1 = (int) highBits;
    //int i2 = (int) lowBits;
}
```

Tested using a ConcurrentDictionary and the above was over twice as fast.
Taking locks on the inserts is expensive.

Comment: nice. yah i thought about using hashset of my elements (just override my element GetHasCode to return the key. but i wasn't aware of UnionWith method.. very cool

Comment: And you need to override Equals.  But if you have a prefect hash then is is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be suitable for an event based solution. Basically assign events for the completion of data for each of your sources. Keep a global concurrent hash with type . In your event handlers go over the completed data source and if your concurrent hash contains the key for the current element just add it to the list if not just insert a new list with given element.

But depending on your performance requirements this may overcomplicate your application. Your first method would be the simplest one to use.

Comment: thanks.. this is what #2 approach proposal is.. i'm just not sure how well this will work with 3 threads updating that same hash..

Comment: .NET does not have a concurrent HashSet to my knowledge.